# Starting the ipython notebook

Tags: python

In an ubuntu terminal window when the notebook is starting this error is raised. Could anybody explain this error

```
KeyError: 3
ERROR:root:Exception in I/O handler for fd 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 330, in start
    self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
```

Comment: I've google around and this seems to be a problem relating to SSL. Is there anything unusual about the way you installed ipython? Also please provide details about your OS and anything else might be relevant

Answer (score 15):

I had to upgrade pyzmq to get it working:

```
sudo pip install pyzmq --upgrade
```

If the problem still persists try upgrading the rest of the libraries which are:

```
sudo pip install jinja2
sudo pip install tornado
```

If you don't wanna be messing around with these libraries you could run a virtual environment and install everything there. Here is the documentation: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: I had the same problem, and upgrading pyzmq as you did above seemed to fix it for me (I was forced to upgrade tornado before this problem was encountered actually).