# Remote access to ipython notebook server throws exception

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have successfully started my notebook to run on a server as indicated by:

```
ipython notebook --profile=nbserver
2014-07-18 11:14:05.473 [NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/local/AD/jack/.ipython/profile_nbserver'
2014-07-18 11:14:05.482 [NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: https://c328740.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
2014-07-18 11:14:05.497 [NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/local/AD/jack/.ipython/profile_nbserver
2014-07-18 11:14:05.497 [NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
2014-07-18 11:14:05.497 [NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: all ip addresses on your system]:9999
2014-07-18 11:14:05.498 [NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
```

When I attempt to access it remotely using:

```
https://devs-sandbox02.jfk.ad.radio.com:9999
```

The server goes into a loop repeating the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 346, in start
    self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
KeyError: 6
ERROR:root:Exception in I/O handler for fd 6
```

What is causing this? How do I work around it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23603935/1749888

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795239/starting-the-ipython-notebook/24938101#24938101I think this is not about certificates. I already posted here:

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, and just fixed it by upgrading pyzmq:

```
$ pip search pyzmq
pyzmq                     - Python bindings for 0MQ
INSTALLED: 13.0.2
LATEST:    14.3.1

$ sudo pip install --upgrade pyzmq
```

(Hope this helps anyone else who winds up here like I did!)